# TIBCO EMS connection not resolving in C#

Tags: c#, tibco, ems

I am working with a program that is meant to publish to and read from an existing TIBCO EMS hosted on a server separate from the program. I have referenced the sample code provided with the TIBCO installation, resulting in a big chunk of the program. Here is the code snippet that I am having troubles with:

```
1 QueueConnectionFactory factory = new TIBCO.EMS.QueueConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
2 QueueConnection connection = factory.CreateQueueConnection(username,password);
3 QueueSession session = connection.CreateQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

When line 1 runs, it goes through alright. When line 2 runs, it goes through alright, however, the connection object is null, resulting in an error during line 3 where a NullReferenceException occurs.

I would have at least expected that line 2 would return some sort of error to show that the request timed out, the credentials were wrong, the url is inaccessible, or at least something to let me know what the issue is, but there is nothing like that, until it hits line 3.

Does it have to do with the configuration of my application? All I have done to get this working is include the TIBCO.EMS.dll as a reference and worked with the code from there.

Could it have something to do with the fact that I am connected to a VPN that requires a proxy? If so, how can I set up that proxy in my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I was using the wrong version of the .NET framework to work with the Tibco integration. The version I was using was farther along than the original.

Answer (score 0):

It would think that your server URL is incorrect.

try different urls maybe like tcp://localhost:7222    (where localhost can be the IP/Name of the remote server)

install EMS locally on you workstation and see if you can connect to it.  (Default admin with no password)